# SQLite to Django - join tables with same field names

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm trying to transfer this very simplified query to Django models:

```
select B.value from A join B on A.id = B.id where B.param = "foo" group by B.value;
```

Basically giving me unique `B.value` of rows with common `id`

My models in Django are:

```
#A
id = CharField()
...

#B
id = CharField()
param = CharField()
value = CharField()
...
```

From what I've read, people are against *joining* tables in Django. How does my query translate to Django in simplest form?

I'm almost willing to just execute this query using `django.db.connection` but I'd rather not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to retrieve all the values of `B` which matches a specific `param` value and has a corresponding `id` in `A`.. Right ?

Try this:

```
a_ids = A.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
b_values = B.objects.filter(param='foo', id__in=a_ids).values_list('value', flat=True).distinct()
```

I would encourage you to look at the Queries in terms of a usecase, rather than converting a query to an ORM equivalent.

Comment: The only problem is that it gives me all the existing values, not just unique values. So grouping is missing. Otherwise, thanks

Comment: You can use `.distinct()`